# IntelliJ IDEA Live Template to generate log statement

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-14

```
@Slf4j    
public class LogGenerator {
        public void testLog() {
            String customVariable1 = "Hello";
            String customVariable2 = "World";
    
            log.info("LogGenerator::testLog, customVariable1 : {}, customVariable2 : {}", customVariable1, customVariable2);
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to generate the log statement using a Live Template hotkey?

Comment: Do you need to pass variables to log statement? Could you please show expected result?

Comment: @y.bedrov the log will be "LogGenerator::testLog, customVariable1 : Hello, customVariable2 : World"

Comment: Sorry, could you please provide before/after example to clarify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Step1: add template text

[image]

Step2:Edit variables, `METHOD_NAME` are defined by IDEA, you just need to change the default value of ARGUMENTS.

[image]

step3: add groovy script to default value

```
groovyScript(" def result=''; def result1=''; def params=\"${_1}\".replaceAll('[\\\\[|\\\\]|\\\\s]', '').split(',').toList(); for(i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {     result1 += ', ' + params[i];     if (i==0) {         result+='\+\" ' + params[i] + ': {}, ';      } else {         result+= params[i] + ': {}, ';      } };  return result + '\" ' + result1;  ", methodParameters());}}
```